# Message consumption in clustered environment with WebSphereMQ

Tags: spring-jms, message-listener

I am trying to configure a Spring `JmsListener` on a queue hosted on WebSphereMQ. WebSphereMQ is in clustered environment. My question is that since it is in a clustered environment will messages consumed from the queue be multiple times or just one time?

Comment: My websphereMq is in clustered environment and i am using queue

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the message to be consumed just once. If the message was consumed multiple times that would violate the fundamental point-to-point semantics of a JMS queue. JMS brokers, even if they are clustered, should still enforce basic JMS semantics.